# IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Tags: android

When I run my Android application, I encounter this `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
03-13 18:06:38.648: E/AndroidRuntime(413): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.InternetGMBH.ThousandPS.Activities.DealerDetailsDisplay
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.InternetGMBH.ThousandPS.Activities.DealerListAdapter$1.onClick(DealerListAdapter.java:76)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:209)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:203)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
03-13 18:06:38.688: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I just hit and solved this issue - you need to add all of the dependencies in your android project's pom.xml to your test projects pom.xml with a scope as provided

per this bug report:
http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=142

e.g.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` exception is being raised. Basically class definition is not found in your project.

Check the names of the class properly, and if you are using third party library check the name of the class properly and ensure that library is included (Class name is case sensitive).

Comment: > Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation